# Can't resolve symbol R

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've been working on this bluetooth data transfer project for a while and now while I'm done with it, I keep getting this annoying error nonStop next to another error which is

> Error:(41, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value '@id/edttxt').

Any ideas where's the problem?

activity main

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mybg"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.cy.el.bluetoothtransfer.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="ON/OFF"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selector2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/btnONOFF"/>

<Button
    android:text="Enable Discoverable"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:id="@+id/btnDiscoverable_on_off"
    android:onClick="btnEnableDisable_Discoverable"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnFindUnpairedDevices"
    android:text="Discover"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edttxt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/edttxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:onClick="btnDiscover"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/lvNewDevices"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lvNewDevices"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="#fffffe"
    android:id="@+id/information" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/information"
    android:hint="            Type here :    "
    android:textColor="#fffffe"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/edttxt"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/information"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edttxt"
    android:text="Send"
    android:background="@drawable/selector2"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/sendBtn"/>

<Button
    android:text="Start Connection"
    android:id="@+id/btnstartConnection"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnDiscoverable_on_off"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

BluetoothConnection myBluetoothConnection ;
private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
BluetoothDevice myBluetoothDevice ;

TextView informations ;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
Button btnEnableDisable_Discoverable;
EditText edt ;
Button btnSend ;
Button btnstartconnection ;

public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

public deviceList mDeviceListAdapter;

ListView lvNewDevices;


// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch(state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:


                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Turning Off ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:


                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Turning On ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Broadcast Receiver for changes made to bluetooth states such as:
 * 1) Discoverability mode on/off or expire.
 */
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

            int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (mode) {
                //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:


                    break;
                //Device not in discoverable mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:


                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:

                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Connecting... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Connected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
            }

        }
    }
};




/**
 * Broadcast Receiver for listing devices that are not yet paired
 * -Executed by btnDiscover() method.
 */
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra (BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mBTDevices.add(device);

            informations.setText(device.getName() + " : " + device.getAddress());

            mDeviceListAdapter = new deviceList(context, R.layout.devicelistview, mBTDevices);
            lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Broadcast Receiver that detects bond state changes (Pairing status changes)
 */
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)){
            BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            //3 cases:
            //case1: bonded already
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Bonded ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                myBluetoothDevice = mDevice ;





            }
            //case2: creating a bone
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Bonding ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //case3: breaking a bond
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Not Bonded ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                }
        }
    }
};



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4);
    //mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
    btnstartconnection= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstartConnection);
    informations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
    btnEnableDisable_Discoverable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscoverable_on_off);
    lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
    mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();


    //Broadcasts when bond state changes (ie:pairing)
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);


    btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            enableDisableBT();
        }
    });





    btnstartconnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startConnection ();

        }
    });



    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           byte [] bytes = edt.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
            myBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);


        }
    });





}


public void startConnection (){

    StartBluetoothConnetion(myBluetoothDevice,myUUID);

}















public void StartBluetoothConnetion(BluetoothDevice device , UUID myUUID){



    myBluetoothConnection.startClient(device,myUUID);


}
















public void enableDisableBT(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){

    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Enabling Bluetooth ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBTIntent);


        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
    }
    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Disabling Bluetooth ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
    }

}


public void btnEnableDisable_Discoverable(View view) {


    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);

}

public void btnDiscover(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Searching... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


        //check BT permissions in manifest


        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

        //check BT permissions in manifest


        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


    String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
    String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

    informations.setText(deviceName);
    informations.setText(deviceAddress);

    //create the bond.
    //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Paring with " + deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

        myBluetoothDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
        myBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnection(MainActivity.this);
    }
}}
```

Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cy.el.bluetoothtransfer">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.cy.el.bluetoothtransfer.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: That's because you didn't study how RelativeLayouts work. `edttxt` has not been defined yet, it's defined later in your layout. Either move the button definitions after the EditText OR use this (horrible) syntax: `android:layout_above="@+id/edttxt"` (note the **+** sign). But that's a ***workaround***.

Answer (score 0):

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value '@id/edttxt'). " brecuse there no control of that id 
so  use  `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edttxt"` or define a control with id having edtxt

ask me in case of any query

Answer (score 0):

There are about 3 errors i noted in your layout because the problem is from the layout.

The first is that in the button with button id

android:id="@+id/btnFindUnpairedDevices",

you have the ***layout_toRightOf*** and the ***layout_above*** set to the same value i.e the ***@id/edttxt***

The second is that when you have a child or sibling relationship in a Relational layout only the id attribute takes a ***'+'*** symbol but your layout the textview with

***id="@+id/information*** has

***android:layout_below="@+id/lvNewDevices"***.

I think correcting these should solve the problem.